# Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt. after migrating from 3.5 to 4.0

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I have a winform appln which is refering few C++ dlls. recently migrated from NET 3.5 to 4.0.
after migration, when I close the form, I am getting
"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt." above accessvoilation exception.
and in Net 3.5 version, it is working fine.
I have tried different ways to fix this issue. unchecked "Suppressed JIT optimisation on Managed code" and also suppressing finalise of C++ objects. but still facing the same issue. but I always getting same stack trace when I check in the exception. please help!!!

Comment: Most likely there are more stringent checks in .NET 4.0 than there was in 3.5, so while it may be "working fine" in 3.5, you still need to fix the original problem.

Comment: Try targeting ".NET Framework 4" instead of ".NET Framework 4 Client Profile"

Comment: And the stack trace you always get? What does that say?

Comment: Are the C++ DLLs 64 bit? .NET 4 now by default uses 32 bit unless instructed otherwise, which would give an error similar to the one you're getting. Just go to project settings and explicitly set CPU type to x64.

Comment: Tragedian... thanks for d reply. I get below trace always. at EnterCriticalSection(_RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION* )
   at cCS.Lock(cCS* )
   at cTrace.{dtor}(cTrace* )
   at ABBDK.AMES.CoreSystem.Support.Diagnostic.Trace.Finalize()

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem after upgrading from .NET 4.5 to .NET 4.5.1. What fixed it for me was running this command:

`netsh winsock reset`

Comment: HI, how this is command is going to help for my problem.. pls explain.

Comment: It resets the TCP/IP network stack, which apparently can cause the error you are seeing. It certainly did fix it for me.

Comment: I have to agree with @Cocowalla this is a fix in some scenarios. You can also see connections to Sql Server faulting.  See Microsoft KB's 2568167, 2915689, and 2890857 for some leads/validation.  I had a call with Microsoft PSS and they confirmed this to be a bug in .NET 4.5.1.  I'm not saying that it's the only case, but it's definitely a path to investigate.  We also found an older version of Sophos seemed to be part of the problem.